# Third-party service that syncs preferences? Like MobileMe

Tags: data-synchronization, mobileme, preferences

Are there any third-party software or services that offer [synchronization of user-preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2085) the same way that MobileMe does?

I’m thinking of the user defaults that live inside ~/Library/Preferences/

With conflict resolution and merging of property lists, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a system set up with Dropbox to do something like this.  I have several settings files (.profile, .gitconfig, ~/Applications, etc) living in my Dropbox, and then I run a script to iterate through them and set up symlinks to their appropriate location.

You could probably do something similar, perhaps even by symlinking your entire ~/Library/Application Support folder.